# How to send the campaign ID, when forming store protocol urls?

Tags: uwp

I bring my users from various store apps, to install a particular app, say abc. Now I want to track & get the statistics about the conversions, i.e. from which app, my abc app is installed more. How can I do this? I could see a section in the developers dashboard - "App page views and conversions by campaign ID" where I could see the installations by campaign id. But how to send a campaign id manually, when forming the store protocol url?

```
ms-windows-store://pdp/?ProductId=abc
```

I guess, certainly there will be a way, since I am able to see the campaign id of adduplex there. as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Our team member has reply your question in msdn please follow the following update in msdn.

Comment: Thanks for you answer